# ¿Mostrar datos en texbox c#, editar y actualizar?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio

esta vez traigo un problemita que me está picando. Se trata de que tengo un formulario de una solución web en c# con asp.net que quiero editar. El dato que quiero editar es una tabla llamada Usuario hecha en Sql Server.

Los datos de un usuario en particular los he podido recuperar, incluso los he puesto en el formulario para que se logre ver lo que se quiere cambiar. Pero cuando borro la caja de texto para poner un nuevo dato y presiono actualizar, me guarda los mismos valores que tenía antes que los borrara.

He notado que cada vez que presiono actualizar se carga la página de nuevo desde el Load, que es donde recupero los datos. Por lo que veo ese es el problema. No estoy muy familiarizado con este lenguaje y por eso se me ha dificultado esta sección de actualizar.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        idUsuario = actualizar.getId();
        Modificacion modificacion = new Modificacion();

        txtNombre.Text = modificacion.mostrarNombre(idUsuario.ToString());
        txtCorreo.Text = modificacion.mostrarCorreo(idUsuario.ToString());
        txtUsuario.Text = modificacion.mostrarUsuario(idUsuario.ToString());                

    }
```

La acción que produce el boton actualizar es:

```
 protected void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        String correo = Convert.ToString(txtCorreo.Text);
        String user = Convert.ToString(txtUsuario.Text);
        String estado = listEstado.SelectedValue;


        Actualizacion actualizacion = new Actualizacion();

        if (estado.Equals("Activo"))
        {
            actualizacion.actualizarUsuario(idUsuario.ToString(), nombre, correo, user, "1");
        }
        else
        {
            actualizacion.actualizarUsuario(idUsuario.ToString(), nombre, correo, user,"2");
        }     
    }
```

En pocas palabras mi objetivo es mostrar los datos del usuario en las cajas de texto sin que, cuando borre los datos y escriba la nueva información me siga agregando los valores que encontró de la base de datos. 
Agradecería mucho la ayuda de esta comunidad. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu page load esta recuperando los datos originales y borrando la informacion que enviaste.

Cuando invocas un evento este refresca tu pagina y el page load se ejecuta antes que tu evento Onclick,

para evitar que esto suceda debes revisar la propiedad

```
Page.isPostback
```

Para evitar que tu codigo se repita

```
if(!Page.isPostback)
{
 //tu codigo que solo se ejcutara una vez
}
```